# How to upload an image to sql server in ASP.NET MVC3 RAZOR

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, file-upload

In my ASP.NET MVC3 RAZOR project i have to implement image upload.I have tried different Tutorials and none working fine for me.I have a model ,controller and a view file.
There is as search action ,from the search action the customer List will be loaded with an option to upload Files.
here my question is how to upload  an image to sql server using ASP.Net MVC3 Razor

Model Code

```
namespace Elixir.Models
{
    [Table("tbl_ElixiCustPro")]
    public class ElixiCustPro
    {
        [Key]
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        public int CusId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }




    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult UploadPhoto()
        {
            return View();
        }



        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadPhoto(ElixiCustPro elixi, HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile, int CusId,string Name)
    {
        if (uploadfile != null && uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            elixi.Image = new byte[uploadfile.ContentLength];
            uploadfile.InputStream.Read(elixi.Image, 0, uploadfile.ContentLength);

        }
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ecp.Image = new byte[uploadfile.ContentLength];
                ecp.ImageUrl = "";
                ecp.CustomerName = Name;
                ecp.CusId = CusId;
                ment.ElixiProData.Add(ecp);
                ment.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

View Code

```
 <legend>File Management</legend>

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPhoto", "Home",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                            Customer ID</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CusId, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>

                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                            Customer Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="id" />
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                                    DMIT Image</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```

[image: File Upload Screenshot]

Comment: What did you try so far? The byte array property should be savable as any other property on your object

Comment: @AlexandrMihalciuc  How to save it.. and i have tried different codes but none works for me.So i have deleted those codes..

Comment: What code did you try to save the model in the database? What errors did you get? Don't omit any code from your question. Otherwise how do you expect us telling you what's wrong with your code? You didn't even show it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  I have updated the question with deleted Code..When i click the upload button it just refreshing the page not getting into the controller

Comment: @AlexandrMihalciuc  I have updated the question with deleted Code.

Comment: I suspect you are using LinqToSql, so what happens on  ment.SaveChanges(); does't it throw any exceptions?

Comment: @AlexandrMihalciuc  I dont whether it throws or not because when i click the submit button of the file Upload ,it jsut refresghing the page ,not getting into the controller